# iOS 13 Segmented Control: Remove swipe gesture to select segment

Tags: ios, swift, uisegmentedcontrol, ios13

TLDR: How to remove the swipe/pan gesture recognizer for UISegmentedControl on iOS 13?

Hi, on iOS 13, lots changed with UISegmentedControl. Mostly, the changes were appearance-based. But there is another functionality change that is messing up my app.

On iOS 13, with UISegmentedControls, you can now swipe/pan to change the selected segment in addition to touching the segment you would like to select.

In my app, I basically have a UISegmentedControl embedded in a scrollview. The UISegmentedControl is too long for the screen to display all of the values, so I created a scrollview that is the width of the screen, whose content width is the length of the UISegmentedControl, and to access the non-visible segments, the user swipes the "scrollview" and the segmented control slides.

This worked perfectly up until iOS 13, and now, the user can't scroll the horizontal background scrollview while dragging on the segmented control because I am assuming the scrollview scroll recognizer is overridden by the new scrollview swipe to select gesture.

I have tried even removing ALL gesture recognizers for the UISegmentedControl and all of its subviews recursively, and the swipe to change selection gesture still works... I am stuck.

Thanks, let me know if the problem is unclear

Comment: I haven't looked into this at all but since you had no luck looking for gestures, perhaps none are used and it's implemented with the usual `touchesXXX` methods from `UIResponder`. You create subclass `UISegmentedControl` and try overriding `touchesMoved`. See if that gets you anywhere.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I have a similar setup (`UISegmentedControl` inside a `UIScrollView` bc it's too long and the client didn't want to compress the content to fit). This worked for me (Built on Xcode 11.1):

```
class NoSwipeSegmentedControl: UISegmentedControl {

    override func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

Then set the class of my `UISegmentedControl` to that. In my app this only prevents the swipe-to-select gesture on `UISegmentedControl` objects embedded within a `UIScrollView`. If it is not in a `UIScrollView` nothing behaves any differently. Which makes sense because `gestureRecognizerShouldBegin()` returns `true` by default. So *why* this allows the `UIScrollView` to take priority on the swipe gesture, I have no idea. But hope it helps.

Comment: This simple and elegant solution worked perfectly. Problem solved. There should really be better documentation noting the changes with each iOS update to the functionality of system UI elements. And even better, attributes like this that affect the behavior of elements should be able to be tweaked during initialization or with an instance variable. Thanks so much!

Comment: The answer is, by override the gestureRecognizerShouldBegin, you allow the scroll view's pan gesture recognizer to begin tracking, which overtakes segmented control's touch handling. If you call `super.gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(gestureRecognizer)` you can actually see it returns `false` (UISegmentedControl rejects gestures it receives).

Comment: This solution resolved the swipe issue on UISegmentedControl however it makes the segments hard to select. Am I the only one who suffer it?

Answer (score 3):

I upgraded @Aystub's answer. You can only allow UITapGestureRecogniger to select a segment.

```
class NoSwipeSegmentedControl: UISegmentedControl {
        override func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {

            if(gestureRecognizer.isKind(of: UITapGestureRecognizer.self)){
                return false
            }else{
                return true
            }

       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using this code allows the segmented control to still be swiped UNLESS it's embedded in a `UIScrollView`. This is the smallest tradeoff in functionality in my opinion

```swift
final class NoSwipeSegmentedControl: UISegmentedControl {

    override func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        guard type(of: gestureRecognizer).description() != "UIScrollViewPanGestureRecognizer" else {
            return true
        }
        return super.gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(gestureRecognizer)
    }

}
```