# Swift 5 Segmented Control Truncates the Titles

Tags: swift, swift5, uisegmentedcontrol, nssegmentedcontrol, segmentedcontrol

I am using dynamic segmented control. Whenever user adds new decks, the title is showing up in the segmented control.

[image]

However, I need a horizontally scrollable segmented controller that might have different title width depending on the text (title) size.

Comment: You will need to use a collection view not a segmented control.  Segemented controls won't scroll the way you want.

Comment: it works actually.  I added the solution here. thanks

Comment: I guess that depends on how you define 'work' - see the comments by the OP below,  IMO this is a very poor UI/UX and I wouldn't put it in any of my apps, especially when UIKit provides a far better native solution to do this.

Answer (score 1):

this helped me to achieve it. [iOS 13 Segmented Control: Remove swipe gesture to select segment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58177165/ios-13-segmented-control-remove-swipe-gesture-to-select-segment)

I added my segmented controller inside of scroll view.
Then changed my segmented controller class to the following;

```
class NoSwipeSegmentedControl: UISegmentedControl {

    override func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```